# Can I start a SAS program van Windows CMD and execute it right away?

Tags: sas

Currently I am able to start via cmd a chosen SAS file and of course the Enterprise software with it.

`start "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Integration\22702985-9221-4F4A-8F7E-921C8EBD7CD6\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesX64\sasenterpriseguide\945\SASEnterpriseGuide\7.1\SEGuide.exe" "C:\test\Test.sas"`

Still I have to click the RUN button to execute this afterwards.

Is there an option in the SEGUIDE.exe to run it right away? for example /r or /run?

I did set up the option to start the code in SAS in the SAS enterprise software, however, I still need to manually start it.
My hope is that there is an option to "open and start" the code in SAS.

Comment: You are not starting SAS with that command.  That is for starting Enterprise Guide.

Comment: Do you have SAS installed locally on your PC, or are you using Enterprise Guide to connect to a remote SAS server?

Answer (score 0):

If your application for submitting a .sas file is Enterprise Guide, you can try the approach discussed in this SAS blog post https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/05/03/using-sas-enterprise-guide-to-run-programs-in-batch/

> SAS Enterprise Guide has always offered an automation object model, which allows you to use scripting languages (such as VBScript or Windows PowerShell) to call the application's features from within other processes. (See Microsoft's "scripting center" for quick access to All Things Scripting for your Windows PC.)

...

> You can write your own scripts to automatically run tasks, projects, or SAS programs at any time.

> The automation model even allows you to create a new project on-the-fly, and add SAS programs into the project and run them.